# When connection to facebook is slowed down the site loads slowly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, facebook-pixel

We have a public website. It contains the Facebook Pixel script.
However, in our region sometimes the speed to the Facebook drops down dramatically whereas the rest of the Internet works fine. When it happens the main page loads very slowly. This is the script located in the head of the page:

```
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '123456');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

As far as I know this script should load asynchronously but it seems that is doesn't, because the page cannot render completely until the facebook pixel finishes its work. I even set the `pagespeed EnableFilters defer_javascript` in the pagespeed module of my nginx but it doesn't help.

What can I do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `<script async>` in your tag. P.S only works on external scripts using `src`.

Comment: _“What can I do? What am I doing wrong?”_ - probably nothing, and probably nothing. You might just have to decide whether sniffing on users all the time is actually more important to you in the end, than overall good performance of your site … :-)

Comment: @CBroe, even `defer` and `async` tags won't help me?

Comment: This code _is_ already written to load the SDK asynchronously, and the script element it dynamically creates and inserts into the document to load the external resource _already_ has the `async` flag set (`t.async=!0;`) _“This is the script located in the head of the page”_ - putting it at the end of body is the only thing I can think of that could possibly further improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding to the script tag itself to deferscript

`<script defer>`

You could try `async`, but I'm sure it doesn't work on the inline script. If you're pulling in the facebook javascript file, then you could async that too.

`<script async>`

This way, you won't need pagespeed to do the deferring

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will check your solution and write to you back.